# Mongoose query returning value even when not expecting it - using time cutoffs

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose query for a Mongo instance where I have a DB which contains a bunch of records where I want to get all documents where the 'stripe.trialEnd' is older than the current time but where the 'stripe.isPaid' value is false. I wrote this query and it seems to select fine based on the isPaid value but will always pick up a value for the cutoff. I am looking for how I can get this query to work correctly.

```
let cutoff = new Date();
Company.find({'stripe.trialEnd': {$lt: cutoff}, 'stripe.isPaid': { '$in': ['false', false]} })
```

Example DB document

```
{
_id: <123abc>
   stripe: {
      isPaid: false,
      trialEnd: 1608943761 // Epoch time
   }
...
}
```

A similar post that I modeled my query after: [Querying with mongoose and dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554943/querying-with-mongoose-and-dates)

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the issue, so mongoose isn't converting the date to epoch time and therefore the compare is returning false all the time and giving me results. I changed how I create the date to give me epoch time seen below, that seems to have resolved the issue.

```
let cutoff = Date.now();
```