# How to get mongo documents created in the last 24 hours using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this mongoose schema

```
const PictureSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        minLength: 3,
        maxlength: 80,
        required: true
    },
//other fields
}, {timestamps: true} );

module.exports.Picture = mongoose.models.Picture || mongoose.model('Picture', PictureSchema);
```

this is an example of generated document

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6266a2a4d3df24b752800c77"),
        "user" : ObjectId("6256946abe645f2e686cc3e3"),
        "title" : "test upload",
        //other fields
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-04-25T13:31:16.303Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-04-25T13:31:16.303Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

knowing the user, how can I get all the documents created by a specific user in the last 24 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const previousDay = new Date();
previousDay.setDate(previousDay.getDate() - 1);
Picture.find({ 
  user: new Types.ObjectId(userid),
  createdAt: {$gte: previousDay}
});
```

Comment: this will probably returns all the documents in the last 24 hours by ALL users.

Comment: it does not work anyway.

Comment: @user3174311, that must work. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17555650/6999951 The code is valid. If it is not working, then it must be for different reasons. Also, regarding `specific user`, simply add one more property `user` and pass the user id as value. It will work.

Comment: you right there's a problem with my code

Answer (score 0):

```js
const picturesInLast24Hours = Picture.find({
  user: new Types.ObjectId(userid),
  createdAt:{$gte: new Date(Date.now() - 24*60*60*1000)},
  // additional filters...
})
```

Comment: it is returning all the documents. Is that maybe because there are not documents in the last 24 hours?

Comment: @user3174311, can you check the `createdAt` field for the documents?